# Can't position link at bottom of DIV

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to have a full screen header and at the bottom of that (but within it) have a link which says learn more. Then below the header have the rest of the website content, in this case "test".

The two issues I have is:

- Learn more should sit at the bottom middle but it doens't, it sits slightly to the right
- The div class "content" is sat within the gray box not under it.

This is the code I am working with:

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.header {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: lightgray;
    text-align: center;
    min-height: 350px;
    position: relative;
}
li {
    list-style: none;
}
.nav {
    display: block;
    padding: 20px;
}
.nav img {
    float: left;
}
.nav ul {
    float: right;
    font-size: 0;
}
.nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
.nav ul li:first-child {
    padding-left: 0px
}
.nav ul li a {
    padding: 0 10px;
}
.learn {position: absolute; bottom: 0; width: 200px;}
.content {background-color: blue; display: block;}
```

```html
<html>
    
    <body>
        <div class="header">
            <div class="nav">
                <img width="39" height="35" alt="" src="#">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Services</a>

                    </li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Writings</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a>

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
                <span class="billboard">Hello!</span>  
                                <a class="learn">Learn More</span> 
        </div>
            <div class="content">Test</div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: For starters, your HTML isn't properly formed. You have mismatched tags. Run it through a validator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an unclosed `anchor` tag. And you need to set `left: 50%; width: auto;` to your `.learn` class in order to center it.

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.header {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: lightgray;
    text-align: center;
    min-height: 350px;
    position: relative;
}
li {
    list-style: none;
}
.nav {
    display: block;
    padding: 20px;
}
.nav img {
    float: left;
}
.nav ul {
    float: right;
    font-size: 0;
}
.nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
.nav ul li:first-child {
    padding-left: 0px
}
.nav ul li a {
    padding: 0 10px;
}
.learn {position: absolute; bottom: 0; width: auto; left: 50%;}
.content {background-color: blue; display: block;}
```

```html
<html>
    
    <body>
        <div class="header">
            <div class="nav">
                <img width="39" height="35" alt="" src="#">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Services</a>

                    </li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Writings</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a>

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
                <span class="billboard">Hello!</span>  
                                <a class="learn">Learn More</span></a>
        </div>
            <div class="content">Test</div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To center align 'Learn more', use

```
 .learn {
  position: absolute; bottom: 0; width: 200px;

  left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%);
 }
```

Before the content, `<a class="learn">Learn More</span>` closing tag should be `</a>`

https://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/efty6zjL/